# Update xml file contents to prevent xml parse error in logstash

Tags: ruby, xml, filter, logstash

I have a number of (~10k) XML files that have a missing closing root tag. When I load this file to logstash with xml filter I get parse error.
Is there a way to make logstash add a closing tag in filter before parsing the content?
Given below is my XML:

```
<root> 
   <elm>....</elm> 
   <elm>....</elm> 
   <elm>....</elm> 
   <elm>....</elm>
```

I looked at filters and couldn't figure out how to add closing root tag to the read content. Please help.

Is there a way where in I can access the file contents from input { } in filter { } section? If I can write some ruby code to modify the read file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your filter section as the first rule.

```
mutate {
                replace => {
                        "message" => "%{message}</root>"
                }
        }
```

This will append closing tag to the file content. Happy coding! :)